# Forwarding the const-ness of a template parameter, should I use a forwarding reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constants, forwarding-reference

I want to write a function `foo` that should call `operator()` of its parameter, as illustrated in the (broken) code below:

```
template <typename T> void foo(const T& x){
    x();
}

struct MyFunctor{
    int data;
    void operator()(){
        /* stuff that might modify the data */
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo(MyFunctor{});
}
```

Obviously the code doesn't work, because `operator()` is non-`const`, but `foo()` requires its parameter to be `const`.

As a template function, `foo()` should work with both `const` and non-`const` functors, and not be picky about the `const`-ness of its argument.

If I change `foo()` by removing the `const` to the following:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T& x) { /* ... */ }
```

... it also won't work because you can't convert an rvalue reference to a non-`const` lvalue reference, so `foo(MyFunctor{})` cannot be called.

Changing `foo()` to a forwarding reference resolves all the problems:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T&& x) { /* ... */ }
```

But is this the "right" way?  Shouldn't forwarding references be used only with `std::forward()` (i.e. the parameter shouldn't be touched apart from forwarding it to another function)?

Comment: You may want to read [Universal References in C++11—Scott Meyers](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers). It contains some in-depth explanations of `T&& x` use.

Comment: This is perfectly fine IMO

Comment: I'm honored to have people with six-digit reputations answer my question!

Comment: That’s how they get six-digit reputations, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a forwarding reference is the right way, and if it calms you, you can certainly forward the parameter:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T&& x){
    std::forward<T>(x)();
}
```

Now it even works with ref-qualified call operators.

Comment: Ref-qualified call operators are something new you taught me today.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the entire purpose of a forwarding reference.

> the parameter shouldn't be touched apart from forwarding it to another function

Which is exactly what you're doing.